# handover variable number of arguments to function from list or vector in R

Tags: r, list, function, arguments

I am writing an function in R which basically uses the GenTable function from the topGO package and a working variant looks like this:

```
function(data=df, arguments=vec){

  return(GenTable(data,
                  classic.fisher=classic.fisher,
                  classic.ks=classic.ks,
                  orderBy="classic.fisher",
                  ranksOf="classic.ks",
                  topNodes=10)
)}
```

I would like to make this function a bit more flexible regarding their arguments in a way like shown below (code is of course not working):

```
function(data=df, arguments=vec){

  return(GenTable(data,
                  optional1=foo1
                  optional2=foo1
                  ...
                  orderBy="classic.fisher",
                  ranksOf="classic.ks",
                  topNodes=10)
)}
```

the values for arguments (which can also be used as argumentnames at the same time) optional1, optional2 etc. are stored in a vector which looks like this:
`vec <- c("classic.fisher", "classic.ks")` BUT this vector is defined by the user and can therefore vary in length, which means it could also look like this: `vec <- c("classic.fisher", "classic.ks", "elim.ks", "elim.fisher")`
my goal is to make the function reading in this vector (vec) and add as many optional arguments as this vector has elements

I played around with eval, parse and so on but nothing worked out

In the end I would like to get something like this (which of course is not working):

```
function(data=df, arguments=vec){

  return(GenTable(data,
                  *vec*,
                  orderBy="classic.fisher",
                  ranksOf="classic.ks",
                  topNodes=10)
)}
```

Comment: This should be done with named arguments in a list, not an unnamed vector. Then you can do `do.call("GenTable", c(data = data, arguments))` inside your function

Answer (score 0):

```
get.GOdata.gentable.list <- function(GOdata=GOdata.list[[1]],
                            GOdata.runtest=GOdata.res.list[[1]],
                            sort.by="classic.ks", ranks="classic.fisher", 
                            no.nodes=10){

gentable.data <- list()

for (i in 1:length(names(GOdata.runtest))){
 gentable.data[[length(gentable.data)+1]] <- GOdata.runtest[[i]]
}

gentable.data[[length(gentable.data)+1]] <- sort.by
gentable.data[[length(gentable.data)+1]] <- ranks
gentable.data[[length(gentable.data)+1]] <- no.nodes
names(gentable.data) <- c(names(GOdata.runtest), "orderBy", "ranksOf", "topNodes")

return(do.call(GenTable, c(object=GOdata, gentable.data)))
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The code finally does what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your input, it definitely was the neccessary hint.

A few comments on my code/R objects in case somebody else is trying to implement something similar.

The GOdata.list object contains GOdata information obtained by coding according to the topGO manual and finally looks (for three different studies (= GSE)) like this:

[image: GOdata.list]

The second object that is plugged in, namely GOdata.res.list is an object obtained by applying the runTest function from the topGO package to the previosly described GOdata.list object:

[image: GOdata.res.list]

Let's get deeper into my function. The gentable.data list contains several arguments for sorting, ranking and defining the number of printed out nodes. Additionally within the for loop, all datasets(!) contained in the runTest object (GOdata.res.list) which correspond to the different previously used methods (classic/elim/etc. + fisher/ks/etc.) are added as argument to the gentable.data list.
In my case this list looks like this:

[image: gentable.list]

Finally the gentable is created and can easily be printed out:

[image: gentable]

I decided to upload so many screenshots and the whole code as usually I takes me so much time and effort to get code I grabbed from stack overflow running as I mostly don't know how the plugged in data looks like.
I hope by uploading this I can at least help some others.
Cheers